# How do I end loop back to beginning in Fancybox 2

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I'm putting together a site that involves a lightbox (fancybox 2). It works great. One change I made for the client was in the CSS so that the previous and next arrows would be "visible" all the time, rather than only when hovering over the box. Seemed to make it more intuitive.

The thing I am now wondering is HOW can I change it so that when one OPENS the fancybox there will only be a NEXT arrow until the second (and subsequent) pictures open -- AND only be a PREVIOUS arrow when one gets to the end? In other words, how do I make it not loop back to the first picture? I went in the js file and changed loop to "false", but that didn't seem to do the trick.

Anyone here familiar with how to accomplish this?

Here's a link to the site. If you click on the fourth thumbnail and click through the pictures you will see what I mean. I'd like it to be one-directional, not circular or "looping" back to the first.

http://www.watercolorsplus.com/New/landscapes.html

Any help appreciated!

Dave

Answer (score 1):

This CSS make the arrows permanently visible

```
.fancybox-nav span {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

... and setting `loop` to `false` in your API options like

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        // API options
        loop : false
    }); // fancybox
}); // ready
```

... will make fancybox to show only the `next` *arrow* while in the first item of the gallery and only the `prev` *arrow* while in the last.

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/z8L2rtvz/)**

**Notice** that you don't have to change either the original fancybox *js* or *css* files but do these changes in your own custom script/css files (and placing them after you load the fancybox files)

Comment: Thanks, JFK. I was on the right track, just a comma away from having it right. But yes, your answer was spot on!